# increment one day format date (not number) javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use `fechaMinima` as the date resulting from today plus one day.

Then I tried the following:

```
hoy = new Date();
fechaMinina = this.hoy.setDate(this.hoy.getDate() + 1);
```

But when I print the result of each I get the following:

```
// hoy
Wed Aug 07 2019 17:26:32 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú)

// fechaMinima
reserva.component.ts:66 1565216792817
```

How do I get `fechaMinima` to appear in date format like `hoy`

Answer (score 2):

The reason is setDate() will change hoy and return the timestamp. You can refer my following snippet.

```js
const now = new Date();

console.log(now);

const tomorrow = new Date(now);
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

console.log(tomorrow);
```